# How does IIS forward HTTPS requests to Kestrel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have a web application written in ASP.NET Core. By default, Kestrel is used; I am hosting it on IIS. I want to have https configurable from IIS. Will kestrel "just know" how to handle this? Is anything required to make https work with Kestrel over the reverse proxy?

Comment: Did you try it out?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows And/Or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @user3358417; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special, Just :

1. Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle on the IIS server. (Restart the Server)
2. Create the Website on IIS.
3. Publish your project into Website.
4. Add Site binding for Https to your Website.

Done.

More info : [Publish an ASP.NET Core app to IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Then what is the purpose of https redirection configured in startup file?

Comment: Hi can you please help me with answer to the above comment?

Answer (score 0):

I did some test on IIS

When deploy the asp.net core application to IIS

The Kestrel will not be used anymore.

Instead , the asp.net core use HttpSys

for example

```
ctx.Response.Headers.GetType().FullName
is 
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection"
```

These kind of classes are in the assembly :

C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.1.3\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.dll

So, IIS will accept both 80 and 443 requests and redirect to asp.net core

(No need to configure SSL for Kestrel)

Hope this helps